# Apparently ++ means +4 or +8 for an Objective-C integer property

Tags: objective-c, integer, post-increment, nsinteger

For some reason, when I try to increment one of my integers, it increments by four instead of one! The only thing I can think of is something wrong in the .h file. The integer is declared like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int *number;
```

and in the code I increment it by doing `self.number++;`. I already checked and the method only runs once before it shows on the screen, and when I `NLog`ged directly around it, it shows it incrementing by 4. To make matters worse, I tried changing it to `NSInteger` for hahas and it incremented by 8!

Comment: the * is denoting that your property is a pointer, so when you increment you are incrementing by the data size to the next address. @Sulthan has the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `*` from the property definition.

When you have `int`, `++` is integer increment. However, when you have an `int*` you have a pointer and `++` is pointer increment, moving the pointer by the size of an int (`sizeof(int)`).

Comment: like I said easy points lol. I'll mark this correct when the timer is up! Thank you!